# Retrieve all guildmembers in the same guild as you using Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery, pfuser

how do i retrieve all the guildmembers in your guild using parse?

Here is my code:

```
PFUser *currentuser = [PFUser currentUser];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[query whereKey:@"connectedGuild" equalTo:currentuser[@"connectedGuild"]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"There are %d guildmembers. Error:%@", comments.count, error);
}];
```

My log:

> There are 0 guild members. Error:(null)

connectedGuild is a pointer to a guild class where i store all the guilds.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right class name and key? You code looks right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries of the `PFUser` class must be instantiated a little differently. Try this:

```
PFUser *currentuser = [PFUser currentUser];
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"connectedGuild" equalTo:currentuser[@"connectedGuild"]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"There are %d guildmembers. Error:%@", comments.count, error);
}];
```

For more information, see the Parse.com website here: 
https://www.parse.com/questions/get-pfuser-in-pfquery-using-ios-api